# I am trying to do a renewcommand on \thequestion for an exam. The command produces the output I want but produces errors

Tags: exam

The command in question is `\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\text{Question }\arabic{question}}`

You can find it in the project https://www.overleaf.com/read/tqkwqvpfcqmg (file is longanswer.tex). The command itself seems to work, the output looks like -

Question 11. (6 marks)

which is what I want. The problem is that it generates an error and that causes problems further into the document.

Comment: Hi Gary, the link is broken. You should not use `\text` outside of math mode, this is probably the source of your error. Try replacing `\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\text{Question }\arabic{question}}` with `\renewcommand{\thequestion}{Question \arabic{question}}`

Comment: Please, don't add code as an external link: you can provide a minimal example in the question. Besides, the present link is invalid.

Comment: Thanks @UdiFogiel your answer was correct, I shouldn't have put the \text in.